# Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found. flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

I am creating a project that connected to a firebase, but I think the problem not in the firebase......

I found this error when I am trying to run the project:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'D:\Aradi Online\my_project\aol\android\app\build.gradle' line: 25

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Plugin with id 'kotlin-android' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4m 24s
```

and this is the `build.gradle`

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.aol"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

I tried to figure this error but I can't solve it as the error says in the below line:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
```

as I have already added this plugin.........

So how can I solve this?...........

I am sorry if there's something missing.....

I hope someone could help me to solve this :D.............

Comment: for using firebase you need to add `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Comment: and make sure you install kotlin plugin in your android studio

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin plugin might be missing. Make sure that the dependency has been added on your Android build's top-level build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.21'
    repositories {
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```